# Scope of functions in package-scoped class

Tags: java

Say you have a package-scoped class:

```
class MyClass {
}
```

What is the difference between

```
class MyClass {
    public f() { ... }
}
```

and

```
class MyClass {
    protected f() { ... }
}
```

and

```
class MyClass {
    f() { ... }
}
```

?

Since the class is package scoped, what will making the function `public` or `protected` do or add?

My reasoning for a package-scoped class:

- You can't use the class from outside the package since it is package scoped, so `public` has no additional effect.
- Following the same reasoning, `protected` has no additional effect, as you must stay within the package anyway.
- Therefore, only `private` has limiting effect as the other 3 modifiers (*package*, `public`, `protected`) are all the same.

Is this correct?

I don't see the difference between the modifies when the class is package scoped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private)

Comment: @TrầnAnhNam I understand the difference between the modifies, but not when the class is package scoped.

Comment: In that article show the accessible by modifier in package scoped. Your class is package scope, but its sub class may be not.

Comment: If a class is package scoped, how can you make a sub class from that class which is not in that same package?

Comment: @JadeDezo Tran mean, some public class X extends your package scoped  Y class. That is allowed however still only private makes sense and remainin modifiers won't serve any purpose

Comment: If a public class `A` extends your `MyClass` in same package, and if class `B` in another package extends `A`, `B` can access public, protected member of `MyClass`.

Comment: Oh right, I did not think about that. THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Though public and protected are redundant in default classes, still private have some meaning for them.

As pointed out in comments, in a inheritance cycle, though not directly, indirect children may get access through some other public class and hence they come handy in cases.

Otherwise, you already decided to make the whole class as package protected, apparently the inner level accessibility goes meaningless anyway.

In short you have chosen upper level against lower lever in terms of accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!